# React: Add Event Listener to props without wrapper html tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I would like to add Event `onMouseEnter` to component prop without wrapper HTML tag.

```
var tooltipText = this.props.children;
<span onMouseEnter={this.renderTooltip}>{tooltipText}</span>
```

Is it possible add this event to `this.props.children`, because I can't afford on the wrapper span.

Here is all component code:

```
class FastTooltip extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.renderTooltip = this.renderTooltip.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            tooltip: false,
        }; 
    }
    renderTooltip(){
        this.setState({ tooltip: true });
    }
    render(){
        var renderTooltip;
        var { overlay, placement } = this.props;
        var tooltipText = this.props.children;

        if( this.state.tooltip ){
            renderTooltip = <OverlayTrigger placement={placement} overlay={<Tooltip>{overlay}</Tooltip>}>
                                {tooltipText}
                            </OverlayTrigger>
        } else {
            renderTooltip = <span onMouseEnter={this.renderTooltip}>{tooltipText}</span>
        }

        return renderTooltip;

    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you want the html wrapper? if you don't render the child component then how do you want to detect the mouse enter event on that component?

Comment: Becouse span change HTML strukcture and some elements are displayed incorrectly (CSS). I want render child component, but without span element. I would like to know if it is possible to add a listener to the variable (prop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could map your component's children and return a new element with an event handler. Does something like this get you on the right track?

```
class FastTooltip extends Component {
    render() {
        return React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
            return React.cloneElement(child, {
                onMouseEnter: () => { console.log('onMouseEnter'); }
            })
        });
    }
}
```